# How do I reorder another array based on a sorted array Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Given an unsorted array may contain repeated elements

```
int [] nums = {8,1,2,2,3};
Arrays.sort(nums);
```

Another array

```
int[] count = {0,1,1,3,4};
```

I want to achieve something like this

```
Arrays.reorder(count, k->nums.sort());
int[] count = {4,0,1,1,3};
```

Also consider that the **Count** array is obtained from computation of **nums** array in sorted order.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying given some array A and another B you want B to match the same ranking order as A? I.e. if the highest number in A is at index x, then the highest number in B should be at index x and so on for second highest all the way down to lowest.

Comment: Without more information, there may be multiple solutions.  In some situations if the `nums` array has duplicate values and the `count` array does not then one may not be certain which duplicate index to apply to the `count` arrays values.  So you need to provide a detail explanation (not by example) of what rules apply.

Comment: Your edit didn't explain what you want to do.  You need to specify in words.  Let's assume `nums =  {8,2,1,2,3}` and `count = {0,1,2,3,4}`  Imo, there are two possible answers,  `4,1,0,2,3` and `4,2,0,1,3`.  So which one is it and why?  And if I am wrong, then again, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we sort an array of indexes instead of the original array we get the order of the elements:

```
Integer[] nums = {8,1,2,2,3};

Integer[] order = new Integer[nums.length];
Arrays.setAll(order, i->i);
Arrays.sort(order, (a, b) -> nums[a] - nums[b]);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(order));
```

Gives:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
```

This represents the required permutation of values in the 2nd array.

We can now use a [standard algorithm](https://www.techiedelight.com/shuffle-array-according-to-given-order/) to permute an array according to a specified order:

```
static <T> void reorder(T[] a, Integer[] order)
{
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        while(order[i] != i) 
        {
            swap(a,     order[i], i);
            swap(order, order[i], i);
        }           
    }
}

static <T> void swap(T[] a, int i, int j)
{
    T tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}
```

Putting this together

```
Integer[] nums = {8,1,2,2,3};

Integer[] order = new Integer[nums.length];
Arrays.setAll(order, i->i);
Arrays.sort(order, (a, b) -> nums[a] - nums[b]);

Integer[] count = {0,1,1,3,4};
reorder(count, order);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(count));
```

Output:

```
[4, 0, 1, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it looks like you want to match the ranking order between two arrays. Let me know if I'm wrong here but to break down your example further:

```
// Ranking order here is [4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
int[] first = {8,1,2,2,3};

int[] second = {0,1,1,3,4};
// If we apply the same ranking order to second we get the following
// {4, 0, 1, 1, 3}
```

Assuming that is what you want, something like the following would work. I don't know of a simple library method of doing this.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public final class RankOrdering {

    public static List<Integer> applyRankOrdering(List<Integer> source, List<Integer> target) {
        if (source.size() != target.size()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("source and target must be the same size");
        }

        // Generate the ranking order for the source list: [3, 5, 1, 0, 0] -> [3, 4, 2, 1, 0]
        var sourceSorted = source.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        var sourceValuesToRank = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceSorted.size(); i++) {
            sourceValuesToRank.put(sourceSorted.get(i), i);
        }
        var sourceRankOrder = source
                .stream()
                .map(sourceValuesToRank::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Determine which rank each element of target has
        var targetSorted = target.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        var targetRankToValue = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < targetSorted.size(); i++) {
            targetRankToValue.put(i, targetSorted.get(i));
        }

        // Apply source ranking order to the values from target
        return sourceRankOrder
                .stream()
                .map(targetRankToValue::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var source = List.of(8, 1, 2, 2, 3);
        var target = List.of(0, 1, 1, 3, 4);
        System.out.println(applyRankOrdering(source, target));
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
[4, 0, 1, 1, 3]
```